# How do I sort CloudKit results by modified date?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, cloudkit

I'm trying to order search results by the modified date.
If I wanted to do by creationDate its:

```
query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
```

What's the key for modified date?
A list of all NSSortDescriptor keys or a way to find them would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it on accident after randomly trying 100 things.
It's:

```
query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate", ascending: false)]
```

They key being "modificationDate"
I could still use a list of these a info on how to find them.
-Thanks

Comment: after downloading all my photos from iCloud my app gallery got messed up. I tried to filter with multiple parameters (modified date and creation date) and nothing changed, any idea why? not sure if all the photos have modificationDate != nil

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord Thanks for making me look that up, the reference page actually includes the queryable field names.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply look at the CKRecord keys (metadata) on the Apple website here;
https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckrecord

This is in answer to your last question.